# Ising model but energy is lower only for up-up states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-spin, phase-transition, ising-model

I understand that in the Ising model, when two consecutive spins align, the energy is lower. I wonder if there is a name for a modified Ising model where only two consecutive spins align in the up-up direction when the microstate has a lower energy. I think it is so simple that it must have had a name, and it would be even better if there is a solution! Thank you!

Comment: The most simple Ising Hamiltonian gives an energy of $-J\sigma_i\sigma_j$ for each 'bond' between neighbouring particles $i$ and $j$. If there is an external magnetic field $h$, each site also gets an energy -$\mu h\sigma_i$. Using a magnetic field you can make the system favor the up state: up-up  has lower energy than down-down (or vice versa). Is this what you mean? If not, could you specify more explicitly how you want the interactions to look like?

Comment: It's true that adding a longitudinal term would lower the energy of the microstates containing more "up", but I think it'd lead to a situation where even though 2 microstates have a similar amount of "up-up" pairs, but one would have more singular "up" and thus have lower energy, which should not be the case. That's why I thought it's not a longitudinal field Ising model.

Comment: An example would be $E(|\uparrow\rangle|\uparrow\rangle |\downarrow\rangle |\uparrow\rangle|\uparrow\rangle) = E(|\downarrow\rangle |\uparrow\rangle|\uparrow\rangle|\uparrow\rangle |\downarrow\rangle)$, but that's not the case in longitudinal field Ising model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Reduction to the Ising model

That's just a standard Ising model. Let me explain this for a one-dimensional chain with periodic boundary condition. You can easily adapt the argument for higher dimensions and other boundary conditions.

The point is to realize that the energy between 2 neighboring spins $\sigma_i$ and $\sigma_{i+1}$ in your model is given by
$$
-J\frac{\sigma_i+1}{2}\frac{\sigma_{i+1}+1}{2}.
$$
Indeed, whenever at least one of the two spins is equal to $-1$, this gives you $0$, while you get $-J$ when they are both $+1$. Therefore, the Hamiltonian of your chain is
$$
\mathcal{H}_N = -J\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\sigma_i+1}{2}\frac{\sigma_{i+1}+1}{2}
= -\frac{J}4 \sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i\sigma_{i+1} - \frac{J}2\sum_{i=1}^N \sigma_i - \frac{NJ}{4},
$$
where I have used the convention that $\sigma_{N+1} = \sigma_1$ (periodic boundary condition).
This is just an Ising model with coupling constant $J/4$ and a magnetic field $h=J/2$ acting on each spin (the final constant $-NJ/4$ is of course irrelevant).

#### The Ising lattice gas

One final comment: if you really want a different name for this version of the model, there is actually one: the *Ising lattice gas*. In this model, you do not have spins, but particles. Each site $i$ can either contain one particle (in which case we set $n_i=1$), or zero particle (in which case we set $n_i=0$). The energy associated to two neighboring vertices $i$ and $i+1$ is then equal to $- J' n_i n_{i+1}$. That is, the energy is $-J'$ is both sites are occupied and zero otherwise. This is obviously equivalent to the model you are considering.

More information about the lattice gas can be found in Chapter 4 of [this book](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook).